# How to update a map in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The map contains:

```
          map -> identitiesUserApplyes:
                   userId: "firstname:"...", lastname:"...""
                   userId: "firstname:"...", lastname:"...""
```

every time I update it the user gets switched, I can never have more than one user in the map.
Any help will be much appreciated!!

```
async function updateIdentitiesUserApplies() {
    const persons = collection(database, "persons");
    const userRef = doc(persons, jobToApplyId);
    const subcollectionRef = collection(userRef, "postingJobs");


    const date = new Date();
    const userToUpdate = {
        [userId]: `
          {
            firstName: ${firstName},
            lastName: ${lastName},
            dateApply: ${date},
            jobTitle: ${jobTitle}
          }
        `,
    };

    try {
        await database.collection("persons").doc(userId).collection("postingJobs".doc(docId).updateDoc({
            [`identitiesUserApplyes.${userId}`]:`{firstName: ${firstName},lastName: ${lastName},dateApply: ${date},jobTitle: ${jobTitle}}`
        }))
      
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating document:", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a missing `)` after `collection("postingJobs"` but before `.doc(docId)` in your code that may relate to the issue because it's in a try-catch block.

Comment: Consider using `applicants` for this data as it is more concise and clear. You can then define `createApplication`, `addApplicant`, `removeApplicant` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce this problem with hard-coded values [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-update-map?file=index.js):

```
onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.data());
})

console.log("Clearing our users field...")
await updateDoc(ref, { "users": deleteField() });

console.log("Adding user1...")
await updateDoc(ref, { "users.user1": { name: "Sara Kay" } });

console.log("Adding user2...")
await updateDoc(ref, { "users.user2": { name: "Frank van Puffelen" } });
```

This outputs:

> Clearing our users field...
> Undefined
>
> Adding user1...
> { user1: { ... } }
>
> Adding user2...
> { user1: { ... }, user2: {} }

You can see that this starts with a non-existing `users` field, then adds the first user, and then the second. That last operation doesn't  remove the first user.

---

I recommend trying the link I provided to see if the behavior of my repro makes sense to you. If it does, try to find where your code differs. If you can't, create a similar runnable repro of your problem and we can have a look at that.